# Why Blazor css isolation not work from UI in another class library?

Tags: blazor, asp.net-core-css-isolation

I have a web *executable project* (`client_server`) with **Blazor**:
[client_server](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A38VL.png)
And *class library* (`client_server_ui`) for all pages:
[client_server_ui](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5m5BP.png)

Trying to use CSS isolation, but css-styles defined as `{ExamplePage}.razor.css` are not added to `{AssemblyName.styles.css}`.

To connect, I tried to add to `client_server_ui/_Host.html` the following links:

- `<link href="client_server.styles.css" rel="stylesheet" />` (css file is generated, but does not contain styles from `{ExamplePage}.razor.css`
- `<link href="client_server_ui.styles.css" rel="stylesheet" />` (css file is not generated)

Is there a way to link `{ExamplePage}.razor.css` with CSS isolation from the class library?

`{ExamplePage}.razor`

```
@page "/example"

<h1>Scoped CSS Example</h1>
```

`{ExamplePage}.razor.css`

```
h1 { 
    color: brown;
    font-family: Tahoma, Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif;
}
```